# Асинхронные операции

Tags: visual-c++, c++

Есть ли асинхронные операции в с++?
Или еще какие-нибудь средства...

Мне нужно воспользоваться функцией из стандартной библиотеки. 
Эта функция возвращает управление программе только тогда, когда в нее придут данные с порта. А если данных нет, то она так и будет ожидать. 
Есть ли в с++ возможность принудительно вернуть управление вызывающей функции?

Comment: В C++ -- нет. В используемой системе (винды? линукс? MAC OS X?) -- есть. C++ тут ни при чём. Какая OS?

Comment: @alexlz, Win XP

Comment: @andrw, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный.

Comment: В новом стандарте есть std::future и std::async.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@andrw](/users/4169/andrw) ReadFile позволяет выполнять как синхронное, так и асинхронное чтение, ReadFileEx специально создана для асинхронных операций

В msdn  про ReadFile:

```
  This function is designed for both synchronous and asynchronous operations. For a similar function designed solely for asynchronous operation, see ReadFileEx.
```

Comment: @alexlz, спасибо!)
То, что нужно:)